# Law of Iterated Expectation with Inequality Conditional

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am wondering if $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y<z)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)\mid Y<z)$, for $z\in\mathbb{R}$. My intuition says that it is true, because events of the form $\{\omega:Y(\omega)<z\}\in\sigma(Y)$, however, I'm not sure how to apply the conditional expectation properties to get to the result directly. I have an attempt of proof, however, and I wish to know if it seems correct. It is as follows: Note that $\mathbb{E}(X\mid A)=\frac{\mathbb{E}(X1_A)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$, so we have

$$\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y<z)=\frac{\mathbb{E}(X1_{Y<z})}{F_Y(z)}=\frac{\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X1_{Y<z}\mid Y))}{F_Y(z)}=\frac{\mathbb{E}(1_{Y<z}\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y))}{F_Y(z)}=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)\mid Y<z)$$

Where the second equality follows from the Law of Iterated Expectation, the third follows from $1_{Y<z}$ being $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, as $A=\{\omega:Y(\omega)<z\}\in\sigma(Y)$, and the last one, from the the identity of the expectation conditional on the event A, considering $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)$ a random variable that only depends on $Y$.

Comment: you're probably looking for a more rigorous answer than my comment can provide.... but why can't you simply argue that $A = Y< z$ is just any event and so you're just looking at the law of iterated expectation for $X,Y$ when restricted to a probability law defined by $A$?  (provided that the restriction doesnt lead to division by zero, undefined-ness of various r.v. etc)

Comment: @antkam In this case, the reason why I would like to keep the $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)$ in such an indirect way is because $(X,Y)$ have a jointly normal distribution, and $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)$ has a very nice linear closed form, which would allow me to rewrite the expression in something that depends only on expectations of truncated normals that are also computable without a lot of mess.

Comment: You're explaining your _motivation_ for wanting "$\forall z \in \mathbb{R}: \mathbb{E}(X\mid Y<z)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)\mid Y<z)$" to be true.  I'm saying why wouldn't you just argue it must be true based on the handwavy logic of my last comment, which claims it is "obvious" that $\forall A: \mathbb{E}(X\mid A)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)\mid A)$.  :)  But like I said, if you need a more measure-theoretic rigorous argument, I sadly am out of my depth.

Comment: @antkam I think your logic is true as long as $A\in\sigma(Y)$, which goes along well with my attempt of proof. I feel comfortable now. Thanks!

Comment: @antonzm Your proof is correct.

Comment: @d.k.o. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The question is more about understanding of measure-theoretic definitions than reasoning.

Measure-theoretic definitions start with $\mathbb{E}(X\vert\mathcal{F}).$ Then it extends to $\mathbb{E}(X\vert Y)$ by treating it as an alias of $\mathbb{E}(X\vert\sigma(Y))$, and finally  $\mathbb{E}(X\vert A)$ means  $\mathbb{E}(X\vert 1_A) \equiv  \mathbb{E}(X\vert \{\phi, A, A^c, \Omega\}).$

Let $A = \{Y < z\} \in \sigma(Y)$. Further let $\mathcal{F}_1=\{\phi, A, A^c, \Omega\}$, and $\mathcal{F}_2=\sigma(Y).$ Then $\mathcal{F}_1 \subset \mathcal{F}_2$. Your result $\mathbb{E}(X\mid A)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)\mid A)$ directly follows from a known theorem $\mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathcal{F}_1)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid \mathcal{F}_2)\mid \mathcal{F}_1)$.

PS: If you insist on directly proving instead of applying the theorem, you can make use of the fact that $A, A^c$ form a partition of $\mathcal{F}_1$ , and rules of partitioning, $\mathbb{E}(X \vert \sigma(\Omega_1, \cdots)) = \frac{E(X; \Omega_i)}{P(\Omega_i)}$ on $\Omega_i$. $\int_AXdP=\int_A\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)dP$ since $A \in \sigma(Y)$. The left side gives values of random variable $\mathbb{E}(X\mid A)$ scaled by $P(A)$ for $\omega \in A$, and the right hand side gives values of random variable of $\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y)\mid A)$ scaled by $P(A)$ for $\omega \in A$. Similar conclusion holds for $\omega \in A^c$. Hence the two random variables are the same.

Comment: Many thanks, by relying on the sigma algebra generated by the event A, it makes it crystal clear why the result holds, as a direct implication of the tower property.

Comment: Just an additional question: how do we go from having a conditional expectation on a sigma algebra to a particular event on that sigma algebra? What is the correct way of thinking about it? Does it has to do with the definition of conditional expectation as the average at each possible set of the sigma algebra?

Comment: $\mathsf{E}[X\mid A]$ is a number while $\mathsf{E}[X\mid 1_A]$ is a function of $1_A$.

Comment: @d.k.o. And they must agree for the omegas that fall into event A, right?

Comment: @antonzm Sure. However, "$\mathbb{E}(X\vert A)$ means  $\mathbb{E}(X\vert 1_A)$" is a misleading statement.

Comment: @d.k.o. Do you think the attempt of proof I present is correct?

Comment: @d.k.o. $\mathsf{E}[X\mid 1_A]$ is a random variable, hence a function of the sample space, not of $1_A$. $E[X\vert A]$ is not a number, it should be treated as a random variable. $E[X; A]$ is usually taken to mean $\int_A X dP$ which is a number.

Comment: Only in classical probability theory, $E(X\vert A)$ is a number, which cooincides with mesure-theoretically defined function values on $\omega \in A$.

Comment: In any probability (classical or not) $\mathsf{E}[X\mid A]$ is a number when $A$ is a measurable set having nonzero probability. You may argue that $\mathsf{E}[X\mid 1_A]=\phi(1_A)$ with $\phi(1)=\mathsf{E}[X\mid A]$ and $\phi(0)=\mathsf{E}[X\mid A^c]$.

Comment: @d.k.o. Treating $E(X \vert A)$ the same as $E(X \vert 1_A)$, i.e. as a r.v. is theoretically sound and generalizes to cases when $A$ has measure zero (also covers $\omega \in A^c$). Defining $E(X \vert A)$ as a number is unnecessary and harmful. For example, in the original question, there is no guarantee that $P\{Y < z\} > 0$; hence the question would be invalid under this definition.